# EntityFramework 6 One to One relation no foreign key on one side

Tags: c#, entity-framework, one-to-one

I've searched but didn't find answer for my question. I have existing database, and writing my entities and relations by hand. There are 2 entities:

```
public class Supplier
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int ProductId { get; set; }
  public int ContractorId { get; set; }

  public virtual SupplierParameters SupplierParameters { get; set; }
}

public class SupplierParameters
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int SupplierId { get; set; }
  public string Info { get; set; }
  //other properties ...

  public virtual Supplier Supplier { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to make a relation (fluent api) one to zero where Supplier is required and SupplierParameters is optional. I **DONT** have foreign key in Supplier table pointing to SupplierParameters. There is SupplierId in SupplierParameters pointing to Supplier table.

I've tried something like that:

```
//on <Supplier> entity
HasKey(x => x.Id);

HasOptional(x => x.SupplierParameters).WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.Supplier).Map(x => x.MapKey("SupplierId"));

// and this

HasOptional(x => x.SupplierParameters).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.Supplier).Map(x => x.MapKey("SupplierId"));
```

Doesn't work. Is this mapping possible with foreign key only on one side ?

Comment: Could you provide more infor than "Doesn't work"? Do you have any error message?
I just tried to create your model and it looks like it's working with the following mapping (removed the MapKey from Supplier entity):
`modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>().HasKey(x => x.Id).HasOptional(x => x.SupplierParameters).WithOptionalPrincipal(x => x.Supplier);
        modelBuilder.Entity<SupplierParameters>().HasOptional(x => x.Supplier).WithOptionalDependent(x => x.SupplierParameters).Map(x => x.MapKey("SupplierId"));`

Comment: Provide missing details requested as an [edit] to the question.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

I was getting error:

```
Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name 'SupplierId ' is already defined.
```

the problem is `.Map(x => x.MapKey("SupplierId"));`

I already have `SupplierId` in my entity class, and `.HasForeignKey(x => x.SupplierId)` is not available for 1:1 relation (e.g. WithOptionalDependent). I could comment out `public int SupplierId { get; set; }` and the code would work, but that is a bit risky because during db operations I would have to remember about setting that column in data base.

There is a walk around:
`modelBuilder.Entity<Supplier>().HasRequired(x => x.DT).WithMany().HasForeignKey(x => x.SupplierId)`

Now `Supplier` has its navigation property `SupplierParameters` filled properly.

But now you cant use navigation property on the other site `Supplier.SupplierParameters` because theres a `Multiplicity conflict`